# I want to show that $|f(x)|\le(Mf)(x)|$ at every Lebesgue point of $f$ if $f\in L^1(R^k)$

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, inequality

I want to show this, where $Mf$ is a maximal function, and I have attain
$$Mf(x)-|f(x)|=\sup_{0\le r\le\infty}\frac{1}{B(x,r)}\int_{B(x,r)}(|f(y)|-|f(x)|)dm(y)$$
and I have no idea how to show that RHS is $\ge 0$. 
My guess is to use
$$||x|-|y||\le|x-y|.$$

Answer (score 4, accepted):

By the definition of Lebesgue point, triangle inequality, and the definition of $Mf$, 
$$\begin{split}
|f(x)| &= \left|\lim_{r\to 0}\frac{1}{B(x,r)}\int_{B(x,r)}f(y)\,dm(y)\right| \\
&\le  \lim_{r\to 0}\frac{1}{B(x,r)}\int_{B(x,r)}|f(y)|\,dm(y) \\
&\le  \sup_{r> 0}\frac{1}{B(x,r)}\int_{B(x,r)}|f(y)|\,dm(y) \\
&=Mf(x)
\end{split}$$

Comment: What would happen if $f \notin L^1(R^k)$ ?