# Hardy-Littlewood maximal function $Mf$ is greater than $f$

Tags: real-analysis, fourier-analysis, lp-spaces

Suppose that $f\in L^{1}(\mathbb R)$ and $x\in \mathbb R.$ We denote $B_{x}$ by the ball in $\mathbb R$ with centred $x,$ and $|B_{x}|=$ length(Lebsgue measure) of $B_{x}.$

Put, $Mf(x)=\sup \{|B_{x}|^{-1}\int_{B_{x}} |f(y)| dy: B_{x}\subset \mathbb R\}.$

**My Question**: (1) Why $Mf$ is known as maximal function of $f$ ? (2) Why $|f(x)|\leq Mf(x)$ for all most all $x$ ? (3) Bit rough question: Why this function got some attention by analyst ? (any application ?)

Thanks,

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1. Because there is a maximum (well, supremum) in its definition.
2. Answered here: [I want to show that $|f(x)|\le(Mf)(x)|$ at every Lebesgue point of $f$ if $f\in L^1(R^k)$](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1014502/)
3. The important properties are:  $M$ is a bounded (nonlinear) operator on $L^p$ for $1<p<\infty$, and also from $L^1$ to weak $L^1$. This fact offers more control over the local behavior of $L^p$ functions   than   the finiteness of $L^p$ norm itself. Applications are listed [on Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hardy%E2%80%93Littlewood_maximal_function#Applications).